# Why always same ads with adsense?

Tags: adsense

I have a site where I publish free backup software. The adsense box on my site (codessentials.com) always shows one of 5 backup-related ads. 
On many sites you can see that the adsense box shows ads based on user-interrests and surf-statistics instead of the content of the site on which the adsense is shown.

How can I get adsense to show user-related ads instead of site-content-relates ads on my site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're talking about [Interest-based ads](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/140377?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=23402). If your privacy policy is adequate, you should already be able to run those ads unless you've opted out in the **Allow & block ads** tab.

Comment: "If your privacy policy is adequate": is that something I need to set on my site?